# Spring-Cloud-Gateway support for asynchronous/nio forwarding

Tags: asynchronous, reverse-proxy, nio, spring-cloud, api-gateway

I'm interested in using spring-cloud-gateway as the framework for implementing an api-gateway/edge service to filter and forward all of our client API requests to backend services.  Some of these API calls require slower responses, while others are fast. We want this implementation to support asynchronous/NIO forwarding in order to reduce threadpool contention during high-volume, mixed-traffic (i.e. fast and slow API call) scenarios while still routing all traffic through the same API-gateway.

Does/will spring-cloud-gateway support asynchronous/nio request forwarding?  If so, is there an example that I could follow using the spring-cloud-gateway framework?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Spring Cloud Gateway is based on projectreactor.io so it is non-blocking. What do you mean by "asynchronous/NIO forwarding"?